# Using Sublime Merge with Vagrant

Tags: git, github, version-control, vagrant, sublimemerge

I have a Rails app running local in a Vagrant box. When i make commits from outside de VM console with Sublime Merge but changes are not reflected after `git status`. Although the files are there it doesn't allow to change branches.

What could cause that it?